# how can i make this method reusable?

Tags: java

i have two classes that use a very similar method like this:

```
method classA() {
    some variable initialization
    get this common interface In

    try {
        do something
        In.methodAA();

    catch () {
        do something
    }
}


method classB() {
    some variable initialization
    get this common interface In

    try {
        do something
        In.methodBB()

    catch () {
        do something 
    }
}
```

I want to put, if possible, one method in a  parent class, since the main difference is the method called on the interface. How can that be achieved?

I'm using java7.

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to provide an `abstract` method so that the common interface knows what to call, something like:

```
abstract class Parent {
  public void job() {
    try {
      doJob();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  protected abstract void doJob();
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
  @Override protected void doJob() {
    /* implementation */
  }
}
```

Comment: @solarapricot: no idea, your initial problem looked like requiring part of code to be factored in a super class, and this is usually how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a third utility class

```
static method classC(classType){

    some variable initialization
    get this common interface In
    try {
      do something

      if (classType is A)
        In.methodAA()
      else 
        In.methodBB()

    } catch () {
      do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a common interface implemented by A and B classes

```
interface Behaviour {
    void execute();
}

public class A implements Behaviour {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // do method A logic
    }
}

public class B implements Behaviour {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // do method B logic
    }

}

public class TemplateClass {
    private Behaviour behaviour;

    public TemplateClass(Behaviour behaviour) {
        this.behaviour = behaviour;
    }

    public void commonMethod() {
        try {
            // do something
            // ..

            // call specific logic
            behaviour.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle ex
        }

    }
}
```

Usage

```
//using A class
TemplateClass polymorphicVariable = new TemplateClass(new A());
polymorphicVariable.commonMethod();

//using B class
polymorphicVariable = new TemplateClass(new B());
polymorphicVariable.commonMethod();
```